# How do I move a rectangle using letter a and d?

Tags: java

when I click left key it go left and when i click right key it go right

```
 public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
 if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
 xa = -game.speed;
 if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
 xa = game.speed;
 }
```

I want to know to do the same thing with 'a' and 'd'.

so when i click 'a' it go left and when i click 'd' it go right

how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Use `VK_A` for letter A and `VK_D` for letter D.
Check the [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html) for more.

- To be able to go left/right **only** with A and D, just replace `VK_LEFT` with `VK_A`, and `VK_RIGHT` with `VK_D`, as in the following code:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A)
        xa = -game.speed;
    else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D)
        xa = game.speed;
}
```

- Else if you want to be able to go left with both `LEFT` and `A`, and right with both `RIGHT` and `D`, use the following snippet:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT || keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_A)
        xa = -game.speed;
    else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT || keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_D)
        xa = game.speed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add to your code:

```
 public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
     if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A)
         xa = -game.speed;
     if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D)
         xa = game.speed;
 }
```